# Java 8 Stream unique characters from array

Tags: java, arrays, functional-programming

Trying to write a simple program that will print the unique words from an input array in **Java8** . For example if the input is

```
   String[] input = {"This", "is", "This", "not"};
```

The program should output `[T, h, i, s, n, o, t]` , the order of elements should follow the same pattern as they appear in input. My approach is to `split` the input , then `map`, `distinct` and finally `collect` it toList. But the following code is printing list of streams instead of words, what am i missing?.E.g.

```
String[] input = {"This", "is", "This", "not"};
       System.out.println(Arrays.stream(input)
               .map(word -> word.split(""))
               .map(Arrays::stream)
               .distinct()
               .collect(toList()));
```

Current output

```
[java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@548c4f57, java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@1218025c, java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@816f27d, java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@87aac27]
```

I am interested to see if there are some other ways in Java8 to achieve the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [flatMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) in order to map with the content of the stream . As you noticed that `Arrays::stream` generate separate streams and what you want is to flatten all those streams into single stream E.g.

```
   System.out.println(Stream.of(input)
           .map(w -> w.split(""))
           .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
           .distinct()
           .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Output

```
[T, h, i, s, n, o, t]
```

Answer (score 5):

Java in Action 8 : has nice explanation of using flat map, I am reiterate the solution which is posted earlier and giving the explanation as per the book.

```
String[] input = {"This", "is", "This", "not"};
```

map function returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);

    List<Stream<String>> steramsOfStream = Arrays.stream(input)
            .map(word -> word.split(""))
            .map(Arrays::stream)
            .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    steramsOfStream.forEach(a -> {
            a.forEach(System.out::print);
            System.out.print("\n");
        });
```

This will produce the following output

output : 
[This,is, This, not ]

[image]

flat map Returns a stream consisting of the results of " replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

```
<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper);

    List<String> listOfStringss = Arrays.stream(input)
            .map(word -> word.split(""))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(listOfStringss);
```

produces output : 
[T, h, i, s, n, o, t]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4mNP.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to complement @sol4me's answer:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of(input).flatMapToInt(CharSequence::chars)
    .distinct().mapToObj(c -> Character.valueOf((char) c))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Could probably be written in a more efficient manner.

The JDK doesn't define `CharStream`, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> findUniqueCharacters(String[] arr) {
    List<String> uniqueList = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split("")))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> 1, (v1, v2) -> v1 + v2))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
            .map(e -> e.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return uniqueList;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34496956)